# Network graphs are flat in Grafana using Telegraf (with InfluxDB)

Tags: graph, monitoring, influxdb, grafana

I have a Grafana dashboard with metrics collected in InfluxDB by Telegraf. The issue I encounter is related to the network graphs that are flat.

[image]

My telegraf.conf includes the net plugin :

```
[[inputs.net]]
```

And a test returns data :

```
$ telegraf -config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf -input-filter net -test
* Plugin: net, Collection 1
> net,interface=eth0 bytes_recv=48497859793i,bytes_sent=68085171005i,drop_in=0i,drop_out=0i,err_in=0i,err_out=0i,packets_recv=65927848i,packets_sent=69072905i 1453196173154147048
> net icmp_inaddrmaskreps=0i,icmp_inaddrmasks=0i,icmp_incsumerrors=65i,icmp_indestunreachs=264807i,icmp_inechoreps=38i,icmp_inechos=1077178i,icmp_inerrors=4559i,icmp_inmsgs=1342870i,icmp_inparmprobs=0i,icmp_inredirects=6i,icmp_insrcquenchs=2i,icmp_intimeexcds=774i,icmp_intimestampreps=0i,icmp_intimestamps=0i,icmp_outaddrmaskreps=0i,icmp_outaddrmasks=0i,icmp_outdestunreachs=849867i,icmp_outechoreps=1077178i,icmp_outechos=3i,icmp_outerrors=0i,icmp_outmsgs=1928597i,icmp_outparmprobs=0i,icmp_outredirects=0i,icmp_outsrcquenchs=0i,icmp_outtimeexcds=1549i,icmp_outtimestampreps=0i,icmp_outtimestamps=0i,icmpmsg_intype0=38i,icmpmsg_intype11=774i,icmpmsg_intype3=264807i,icmpmsg_intype4=2i,icmpmsg_intype5=6i,icmpmsg_intype8=1077178i,icmpmsg_outtype0=1077178i,icmpmsg_outtype11=1549i,icmpmsg_outtype3=849867i,icmpmsg_outtype8=3i,ip_defaultttl=64i,ip_forwarding=2i,ip_forwdatagrams=0i,ip_fragcreates=17072i,ip_fragfails=0i,ip_fragoks=8536i,ip_inaddrerrors=0i,ip_indelivers=77465764i,ip_indiscards=0i,ip_inhdrerrors=0i,ip_inreceives=79567433i,ip_inunknownprotos=0i,ip_outdiscards=108775i,ip_outnoroutes=27i,ip_outrequests=70951694i,ip_reasmfails=52285i,ip_reasmoks=1327353i,ip_reasmreqds=2706991i,ip_reasmtimeout=44473i,tcp_activeopens=872419i,tcp_attemptfails=126726i,tcp_currestab=23i,tcp_estabresets=78613i,tcp_incsumerrors=0i,tcp_inerrs=90i,tcp_insegs=43809023i,tcp_maxconn=-1i,tcp_outrsts=113744i,tcp_outsegs=56961459i,tcp_passiveopens=1065318i,tcp_retranssegs=354967i,tcp_rtoalgorithm=1i,tcp_rtomax=120000i,tcp_rtomin=200i,udp_ignoredmulti=0i,udp_incsumerrors=0i,udp_indatagrams=33110797i,udp_inerrors=36303i,udp_noports=232164i,udp_outdatagrams=27459622i,udp_rcvbuferrors=36303i,udp_sndbuferrors=0i,udplite_ignoredmulti=0i,udplite_incsumerrors=0i,udplite_indatagrams=0i,udplite_inerrors=0i,udplite_noports=0i,udplite_outdatagrams=0i,udplite_rcvbuferrors=0i,udplite_sndbuferrors=0i 1453196173155777308
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: What query is Grafana graphing? What are the results of that query when submitted directly to InfluxDB?

Comment: I am sorry @beckettsean in the meantime I switched to collectd to gather metrics, so I don't have the query anymore. But it was definitely a problem querying. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 12):

You're graphing the total number of bytes/packets sent/received since the interface was started. This number will only ever increase. If you want to see these as a rate (eg bytes per second) then you will need to use Influx's DERIVATIVE(1s) function:

```
SELECT derivative("bytes_recv", 1s) FROM "net" WHERE "host" = '1.2.3.4' AND "interface" = 'eth0'
```

Comment: You need an aggregate function inside as well like this: `SELECT derivative(sum("bytes_recv"), 1s)`